# When working with Chrome extensions can you access the original pre-parsed CSS?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Within a Google Chrome extension I am using the DOM api to get the stylesheets and their elements.  These have already been parsed by Chrome by the time I get to see them - is there any way to view the pre-parsed CSS before Chrome gets hold of it through an extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to read the original `*.css` files. If that's what you want, you can simply fetch the files as text files via Ajax and read their contents as strings. (If the files are on a website, not packaged in the extension, ensure sure you have host permissions for that domain, or all domains, depending on your needs.)

Comment: Thanks apsillers, this is how I am currently doing it, but was hoping that as the files have already been handled there may be some way without the need for an additional ajax call

Comment: I see. I'm afraid there's no way to do that. However, you may be interested in knowing that the file will not need to be *transferred* again during the repeat Ajax fetch: the server will return `304 Not Modified` and Chrome will use the CSS file stored in the browser cache.